# Extracting lines with specific character count

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have a python script that is pulling URLs from pastebin.com/archive, which has links to pastes (which have 8 random digits after pastbin.com in the url). My current output is a .txt with the below data in it, I only want the links to pastes present (Example: http://pastebin.com///Y5JhyKQT) and not links to other pages such as pastebin.com/tools). This is so I can set wget to go pull each individual paste.

The only way I can think of doing this is writing a bash script to count the number of characters in each line and only keep lines with 30 characters exactly (this is the length of the URLs linking to pastes).

I have no idea how I'd go about implementing something like this using grep or awk, perhaps using a while do loop? Any help would be appreciated!

```
http://pastebin.com///tools
http://pastebin.com//top.location.href
http://pastebin.com///trends
http://pastebin.com///Y5JhyKQT <<< I want to keep this
http://pastebin.com//=
http://pastebin.com///>
```

Comment: You can do it easily in python so you dont have to get noise to then check it later with wget. See my answer for python below. Do not write to file if its more than than length.

Comment: The line you say you want to keep ends in `Y5JhyKQT` and so does not `have 8 random digits` at the end so I assume you mean `8 random alpha-numeric characters`. How then would you distinguish that from the line you don't want before it that ends in `trends` if it ended in an 8-character word like `trendier` instead of `trends`? Or is that just a completely irrelevant red herring you threw in there and all that actually matters is the line length being 30 characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the sample you posted it looks like all you need is:

```
grep -E '/[[:alnum:]]{8}$' file
```

or maybe:

```
grep -E '^.{30}$' file
```

If that doesn't work for you, explain why and provide a better sample.

Comment: Why not `awk 'length() == 30'` ? That would work without a regular expression and it is pretty clean, isn't it?

Comment: idk if a function call would be any faster than that regexp comparison plus awk has to do do field splitting on every line so I'm about 99% sure the grep would be more efficient as well as being briefer. nbd either way though. I started out thinking the key to this was the last 8 chars being alpha-numeric so that kinda led me down the grep/regexp path.

Comment: It feels like you are right. Splitting into fields is unnecessary overhead. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
while read aline
do
    if [[ ${#aline} == 30 ]]; then                                                                                                                                                         
        #do something
    fi
done
```

This is documented in the [bash man pages](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) under the "Parameter Expansion" section.

EDIT=this solution is zsh-only

Comment: Don't do it. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: whoops, I guess I've been using zsh for far too long

Comment: It'd still be the wrong approach in zsh with (almost?) all of the same issues. A shell is an environment from which to call tools with a language to sequence those calls, it's not a tool to manipulate text.

Comment: My argument is "since we are being provided these tools and we know them, let's use them until they come short.". I'll agree that optimization _may_ be an issue, but until it is, let's just code and relax; preemptive optimization is the root of all. Anyway, this is a discussion without end.

Answer (score 0):

This is the algorithm

- Find all characters between new line characters or [read one line at a time](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects).
- Count them or [store them in variable and get its count](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count). This is the length of your line.
  Only process those lines that are exactly same count as you want.
  In python there is both functions character count of string and reading line as well.